# jquery carousel with non-active images still on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, web, frontend

I'm trying to make a jQuery carousel without using plugins. I've looked all over stackoverflow and google, and all of them have the non-active images go off screen. I am trying to create a carousel with three images where the non-active images stay on screen and shrink a little bit. *

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw9kr.png)

When the right arrow is pressed, the left image moves to the center, the right image moves to the left most position, and the center image moves to the right and vice versa.

How would I go about doing that?

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/A2aZv/ except it's horizontal with arrows and showing the non active images as well.

Sorry if my language is bad, English is not my first language.

Thank you in advance.

html

```
<div id="carousel">
<ul id="carouselNav">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=Image 1" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=Image 2" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=Image 3" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=Image 4" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
/**
 * Check if first li element is hidden
 * then show
 */
if( jQuery('#carouselNav li:first-child').is(':hidden') ) {
    // Toggle visibility
    jQuery('#carouselNav li:first-child').toggle();
}
// Interval time
var carouselInterval = 5000;
// Slider
function carouselSlide(){
    // Check if last element was reached
    if( jQuery('#carouselNav li:visible').next().length == 0 ) {
        // Hide last li element
        jQuery('#carouselNav li:last-child').slideUp('fast');
        // Show the first one
        jQuery('#carouselNav li:first-child').slideDown('fast');
    } else {
        // Rotate elements
        jQuery('#carouselNav li:visible').slideUp('fast').next('li:hidden').slideDown('fast');
    }
}
// Set Interval
var carouselScroll = setInterval(carouselSlide,carouselInterval);
// Pause on hover
jQuery('#carousel').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(carouselScroll);
}, function() {
    carouselScroll = setInterval(carouselSlide,carouselInterval);
    carouselSlide();
});
});
```

css

```
#carousel {
    text-align: center;
    background: #cdcdcd;
}
#carousel ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#carousel li {
    display: none;
}
```